# Can I redirect all links to a live site to a test one?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, testing

I have been asked to sort out a web site for a society, which has been dropped by the previous person who looked after it.

The pages etc are full of direct references to the live site URL - and I would really like to test it before I take over the domain and dump the files in! Not least to check everything works on the new host, and it is not calling some service which is not provided...

But absolutely everything I click on takes me over to the live site.

I suspect I am not the first person to face this, so is there a way for me to intercept and redirect all attempts to connect to the live site, and send them to my test version? Perhaps  by over riding a DNS entry.

This should only affect the test site, as I don't want to damage the live service.

(I tried a global text edit, but for some reason that did not work).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the real domain with your local ip modifying the host file in your computer (if you are using Windows).

Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and look for the hosts file.

Then add an entry in it like:

127.0.0.1     thelivedomain.com

A global text search & replace should work as well but I think the host approach is more safe.